# Problem when using a numpy array of string (format) elements, python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to use an array of string format elements to take a shortcut and automate formatting steps ahead. Short story: it resulted with an error (`unmatched '{' in format spec`). I tried to check what happened by writing and running the corresponding part of the code, step by step:

1:

```
    import numpy as np
    from sty import fg, rs
    
    r=np.array([["{:>{w}.{p}f}"]*6]*3)
    print(r[0,0])
```

output: `{:>{w}.{p}f}`

2:

```
    sc=fg.red + r[0,0] + fg.rs
    sc
```

output: `'\x1b[31m{:>{w}.{p}f}\x1b[39m'`

3:

```
    r[0,0]=sc
    r[0,0]
```

output:`'\x1b[31m{:>{w}.'`

As you can see the part after the dot (`{p}f}\x1b[39m`) is missing. I would like to learn if there is any solution to this.

Comment: Note that both `r[0,0]` strings have a length of 12. This is an indication of buffer length, allocated initially by NumPy.

Comment: It seems weird and inconvenient to me to let NumPy store formatting strings. Perhaps a list (or list of lists) works just as well, and will bypass your current problem.

Comment: i havent tried yet but it seems you see what i miss, i will try to continue with a list or think someting else for the buffersize.